# VisualStudio Default Code Discovery Method

Tags: .net, visual-studio

A little while back (after recently installing VStudio 2010) I used the **Go to Definition...** feature and a little box opened up asking me if i wanted to:

- Use the object explorer
- Open Meta-Data View
- Something I can't remember

Well I wasn't really paying much attention and selected meta-data view, I'd now like to set it to Object Explorer but I can't for the life of me find it in the myriad of VStudio options.

Could someone direct me there before I go insane?

Comment: May not the best solution, but if you haven't done much customisation, you could reset everything to default settings. `Tools...Settings...Reset`. Or, probably better, `Tools...Settings...Import/Export Settings` and then reset after saving your settings.

Comment: I've got a *lot* of changes to my config id rather not lose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Resharper installed? If yes then this how you can change it: [ReSharper 5.0 can Visual Studio 2010 Metadata View](http://blog.aheil.de/2009/12/27/ReSharper50CanVisualStudio2010MetadataView.aspx)

Comment: Oh my god! That's it! :) Thankyou, I had no idea it was part of ReSharper, was looking for it for ages in VStudio's settings. Thankyou so much.

Comment: I can't award the bounty till tomorrow, I'll do it then, once again, thankyou.